# How do I write a custom search filter to weed out R.java files?

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio, file-search

I'm trying to create a custom search à la [How to exclude a file extension from IntelliJ IDEA search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143881/how-to-exclude-a-file-extension-from-intellij-idea-search) in Android Studio. **How come the following pattern doesn't exclude `R.java` files?**

[image: Search for "file:*.java" yielding 1,192 results from 5,256 possible]
[image: Search for "file:*.java&&!file:R.java" yielding 1,192 results from 5,256 possible]

Note that the second uses `&&!file:R.java`, yet the scope does not contain fewer files.

Comment: It's VERY easy to look ONLY in R.java files.  But who needs that?

Comment: @ScottBiggs I think no one does. That is why I wish to exclude all R.java files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that one must take into account the path of the file. `!file:R.java` looks only for `R.java` in the root. To look for all R.Java files, one must use `!file:*/R.java`:

[image: Search for "file:*.java" yielding 1,203 results from 5,304 possible]
[image: Search for "file:*.java&&!file:*/R.java" yielding 1,163 results from 5,304 possible]

Note that the second uses `&&!file:*/R.java`, and the scope contains fewer files.