# How can I exclude all build files in quick file search at Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

When I used Command+Shift+O search file in my AndroidStudio for Mac.The result will has too many unnecessary files like in "build" folder. I've never seen before until recently.How can I exclude these?
[image]

Comment: I believe this question is properly answered here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937468/android-studio-exclude-files-in-build-folder-from-search-result

Comment: Yes, http://stackoverflow.com/a/31293830/1983799 can resolve my question.Thx..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore R.java fies in Find results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22973939/ignore-r-java-fies-in-find-results)

Answer (score 1):

> Android Studio (like its progenitor IntelliJ) allows you to define a
>   custom scope to help you exclude intermediates files when searching.
>
> [image: Screenshot selecting custom option from scope]1]
>
> Here are the steps I use to set this up:
>
> 1. Bring up Find in Path dialog (Ctrl+Shift+F on my machine).
> 2. In the Scope area, select the Custom radio button. Then tap the "..." button on the right side of the dropdown. This brings up the
>      Scopes dialog.
> 3. Click the "+" button on the left side of the Scopes dialog, which will bring up the Add New Scope dialog. Name it
>      "ExcludeIntermediates".
> 4. In the Pattern field, paste in the following pattern and click OK:
>
>    ```
>    !file:*intermediates*/&&!file:*generated*/
>    ```
>
> This pattern excludes R.java files and other intermediates such as
>   layout files in exploded-aar and AndroidManifest.xml copies in
>   filtered_manifests folders.
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/32238593/1815624